# Unable to filter values in the grid

Tags: c#, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I've implemented the following three methods and as far I can see, the breakpoints in each are being hit. However, the filtration doesn't seem to occur in the grid. I've followed [an example - C# version](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/xamDataGrid_External_Filtering.html), although with some adaptation, due to the current environment (we're using *BindingList* instead of the type used in the example.

```
private void GridName_OnRecordFilterChanged(
  object sender, RecordFilterChangedEventArgs e) { ... }
private void GridName_OnRecordFilterDropDownPopulating(
  object sender, RecordFilterDropDownPopulatingEventArgs e) { ... }
private void GridName_OnRecordFilterDropDownOpening(
  object sender, RecordFilterDropDownOpeningEventArgs e) { ... }
```

What can I be missing and how to debug it? Grouping seems to work perfectly so the data is bound as supposed to.

Comment: Not sure what your problems are. When you say filtration doesn't seems to occur in the grid you mean you are applying the filter but the records present in the grid are not as expected. right?

Comment: @Alok Oh, I'm not in that project anymore, so I can't verify and provide more info. Sorry about that. I recall that we get it to work but it was time costly... Same goes for the other question you commented on.